# Is it possible to write custom attributes or annotation in a vala class, like C# or Java?

Tags: annotations, attributes, vala

as the question implies how can one reduce boilerplate code or add custom functionality like for example in Java

```
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED) private String name;
```

or Jackson-annotation `@JsonProperty`
how could one implement or emulate this functionality?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create custom attributes right now.
For properties you can use next syntax:

```
 public string name { get; protected set; default = "42"; }
```

GObject type system also support Json Serialization/Deserialization for properties.
Here small example(valac file --pkg json-glib-1.0):

```cs
public enum MyEnum {
    FOO, BAR, FOOBAR
}

public class MyObject : Object {
    public string str { get; set; }
    public MyEnum en { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }

    public MyObject (string str, MyEnum en, int num) {
        this.str = str;
        this.num = num;
        this.en = en;
    }
}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject ("my string", MyEnum.FOOBAR, 10);
    Json.Node root = Json.gobject_serialize (obj);

    // To string: (see gobject_to_data)
    Json.Generator generator = new Json.Generator ();
    generator.set_root (root);
    string data = generator.to_data (null);

    // Output:
    // ``{"str":"my string","en":2,"num":10}``
    print (data);
    print ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

You can find more on ValaDoc.